# How to apply multi-file diff from Code Collaborator in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

When applying multi-file diff from CC, Eclipse recognizes only the first file from the patch and thinks that changes from the whole patch belong to this first file.

Detailed description: Create a review in CC with more than one file. Select Download diff on the main review page and save the file. Then go to Eclipse, right click some project,  click on Team -> Apply patch and enter the path to the downloaded diff file. Click Next and Eclipse will present the content of the patch incorrectly: it recognizes only the first file and attributes changes from the whole patch to it even though they belong to the subsequent files from the patch.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there some fix or workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

Eclipse requires `Index:` line at the beginning of the changes for each file. It works OK like this:

```
Index: /file1
--- /file1
+++ /file1
_changes in file 1_
Index: /file2
--- /file2
+++ /file2
_changes in file 2_
```

CC diff does not contain `Index:` lines. You can use the following awk script to add them:

```
awk 'BEGIN {minus="## filler"}; /^\+\+\+/ {print "Index: " $2;}; {print minus; minus=$0}; END {print minus}' cc_diff.txt>eclipse_diff.txt
```